# Using dplyr to create a matrix for SNA

Tags: r

Currently, my data looks like this:

| ID | Observation # |
| --- | --- |
| Tom | 1 |
| Sam | 1 |
| Joe | 2 |
| Tom | 2 |
| Sam | 2 |
| Sam | 3 |
| Phil | 3 |
| Tom | 4 |
| Phil | 4 |
| Sam | 4 |

Is there a way to create a matrix with a list of all IDs (Joe, Tom, Sam, Phil) on both the x and y axis, and a count of interactions filling the matrix? For example, the intersection of the Phil column and Sam row would read "2", and vice versa.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way in `base R`

```
lst1 <- split(df1$Observation, df1$ID)
outer(lst1, lst1, Vectorize(\(x, y) length(intersect(x, y))))
```

-output

```
     Joe Phil Sam Tom
Joe    1    0   1   1
Phil   0    2   2   1
Sam    1    2   4   3
Tom    1    1   3   3
```

---

Or a more compact option is

```
tcrossprod(table(df1))
```

-output

```
   ID
ID     Joe Phil Sam Tom
  Joe    1    0   1   1
  Phil   0    2   2   1
  Sam    1    2   4   3
  Tom    1    1   3   3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("Tom", "Sam", "Joe", "Tom", "Sam", "Sam", 
"Phil", "Tom", "Phil", "Sam"), Observation = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```